# cancel with Spring web flow

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

I have a form with the values pre populating from database,
where in the user can change and save the values.

1) I have a adress text prepopulating it from the database and there is a option to amend uk button and click here button it takes to the next page there the address will be populated and if the user wants to change he can change and save or else he can cancel it...but if the address is blank and cancel it even then it is updating with blank values.

```
 <view-state id="selectUKAddress" model="address" view="../updateDetails/selectUKAddress.jsp">
    <transition on="populate" to="ukAddressSelectionAction" />
    <transition on="continue" to="updateDetails">
        <set name="viewScope.addressPayload" value="new onlinereg.action.payload.AddressActionPayload(address, studentData, addressType)" />
        <evaluate expression="addressAction.execute(addressPayload)" />
    </transition>
    <transition on="cancel" to="updateDetails" validate="false" >
    </transition>
</view-state>

 <view-state id="updateDetails" model="studentData" view="../updateDetails/updateDetails.jsp">
    <on-entry>
        <evaluate expression="navigationVO.personalDetails=true" />
        <evaluate expression="navigationVO.activeTab='personalDetails'" />
        <set name="viewScope.disabilityCodes" value="registrationService.getDisabilityCodes()" />
        <set name="viewScope.legacyDisabilityCodes" value="registrationService.getLegacyDisabilityCodes()" />
        <set name="viewScope.ethnicityCodes" value="registrationService.getEthnicityList()" />
        <set name="viewScope.countries" value="registrationService.getCountries()" />
        <set name="viewScope.nationality" value="registrationService.getNationality()" />
        <set name="viewScope.qualification" value="registrationService.getQualification()" />
        <set name="viewScope.university" value="registrationService.getUniversity()" />
    </on-entry>
    <transition on="updateUKHomeAddress" to="selectUKAddress" validate="false">
        <evaluate expression="studentData.homeAddress = addressService.generateUKAddress(studentData.homeAddress)" />
        <set name="flowScope.address" value="studentData.homeAddress" />
        <set name="flowScope.addressType" value="@uk.ac.city.onlinereg.action.AddressAction@HOME_ADDRESS" />
    </transition>
    <transition on="updateNonUKHomeAddress" to="selectNonUKAddress" validate="false">
        <evaluate expression="studentData.homeAddress = addressService.generateNonUKAddress(studentData.homeAddress)" />
        <set name="flowScope.address" value="studentData.homeAddress" />
        <set name="flowScope.addressType" value="@uk.ac.city.onlinereg.action.AddressAction@HOME_ADDRESS" />
    </transition>
    <transition on="updateUKTermAddress" to="selectUKAddress" validate="false">
        <evaluate expression="studentData.termAddress = addressService.generateUKAddress(studentData.termAddress)" />
        <set name="flowScope.address" value="studentData.termAddress" />
        <set name="flowScope.addressType" value="@uk.ac.city.onlinereg.action.AddressAction@TERM_ADDRESS" />
    </transition>
    <transition on="updateHallsTermAddress" to="selectHallsAddress" validate="false">
        <evaluate expression="studentData.termAddress = addressService.generateHallsAddress(studentData.termAddress)" />
        <set name="flowScope.address" value="studentData.termAddress" />
        <set name="flowScope.addressType" value="@uk.ac.city.onlinereg.action.AddressAction@TERM_ADDRESS" />
    </transition>
    <transition on="updateNonUKTermAddress"  to="selectNonUKAddress" validate="false">
        <evaluate expression="studentData.termAddress = addressService.generateNonUKAddress(studentData.termAddress)" />
        <set name="flowScope.address" value="studentData.termAddress" />
        <set name="flowScope.addressType" value="@uk.ac.city.onlinereg.action.AddressAction@TERM_ADDRESS" />
    </transition>
    <transition on="continue" to="finish" />
</view-state>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `bind="false"` to your `cancel` transition(s).

See http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.3.x/reference/htmlsingle/spring-webflow-reference.html#view-bind